# cant get regex to work as i want

Tags: php, regex

With this function:

```
function bbcode_parse($str) {
$str = htmlentities($str);

$find = array(  
    '/\\*\*(.[^*]*)\*\*/is',
);

$replace = array(
    '<b>' 
);

$str = preg_replace($find, $replace, $str);  

return $str;
}
```

And with text "`My name is **bob**`"

I get in source code `Hi my name is <b>`

Been trying to get this to work for a while now.

Would appricate some expert help :)

Comment: perhaps a better title next time

Comment: could not think of better one, suggest a better one and i change :)

Comment: just explain what you are trying to do in more detail than "get a regex to work".  A good rule of thumb is, what would someone google to find your Q/A, if they had the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(In bbcode you bold text with `[b]xxx[/b]` not `**xxx**`.)

In PHP, you can use `$1` to represent the captured subgroup, so your replacement should be

```
'<b>$1</b>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
preg_replace("/.*\*{2}(.+?)\*{2}.*/", "<b>$1</b>", "My name is **bob**");
```